# Static block gets skipped basing on Main method

Tags: java

From the below program I have observed that

1. main() method must and should not required to be only in next level of main class
2. All Static blocks are not loaded first.

I would like to know why the static blocks are not loaded?

```
public class FunnyProgram {

    static {
        System.out.println("Loading first static block");
    }

    static class Inner {
        static {
            System.out.println("Loading first Inner static block first");
        }

        static class AgainInner {
            static {
                System.out.println("Loading second AgainInner static class first");
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("This funny program prints");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Executing the main method only requires to load the class AgainInner. The other classes don't need to be loaded, so thair static blocks are never eecuted.

Comment: But I think the general conception is that static blocks are loaded first. This case I guess I have cleared myself a doubt

Comment: A static block is executed when a class is being loaded and initialized. If a program doesn't load a class, its static blocks are not executed. The fact that the classes are static nested classes doesn't change anything.

Comment: I think only when class is loaded. Initialization loads the block

Comment: That's what @JBNizet just told you. NB The static classes are misnamed. They are not `Inner`. They are nested.

Comment: It can also be termed static inner class

Comment: No. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#d5e11140: *An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared static.*. Static inner class is an oxymoron.